# chatter:feed and apex:form on community custom page

Tags: chatter, community

I'm building a custom detail page for Cases, this page will be accessed through a community. 
I'm using the chatter:feed component to display info related to chatter.
When I added an apex:form to the page it started to display javascript errors and the chatter publisher stopped from working.
Weird issue is that the page works ok when accessed from inside the org, the problem happens accessing via community. This issue is happening with Sys admin user, but it didn't happen with a clone from the standard profile.
Probably there's something i'm forgetting to include or attribute flag i need to set.

i ended up reducing  the code to get to this, and still got the error :

```
 <chatter:feed entityId="{!case.Id}"   />

 <apex:form styleClass="form-horizontal" >
  form body
 </apex:form>
```

Did anyone run into this issue?

thanks,
Andrea